# Invalid literal for int() with base 10 " '123' "

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to change the value of csv column to numeric type as given below:

```
reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=",")
for row in reader:
  print int(row[0])
```

My csv file look like this:

```
'123', '12'
'124', '14'
'125', '15'
```

Any ideas how can I convert this to integer? Thank you.

Comment: try this: print int(row[0].replace("'", ""))  that'll get rid of the ' chars around the numbers in your csv file

Comment: You could use `strip(" '")` to remove surrounding spaces and quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the quoting characters:

Try

```
reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="'")
for row in reader:
    print int(row[0])
```

More information on csv reading/writing is available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Quoting characters are often used to escape commas (or other seperators).

For example, in a csv containing money amounts, in the row:

```
"12,30", "13,00", "14,00", "15,30"
```

The quoting character allows the commas in the numbers to be escaped so that the result is:

```
[12.30, 13.00, 14.00, 15.30] # As a list in Python
```